# How to access naviagtion options from imported file in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-native-gifted-chat

I'm passing data through different pages down to the last page in my app, its been working fine.

But the issue is the last page has 2 components so the typical `</ChatActivity navigation="{this.props.navigation}" />`, here's what I mean:

I have an App.js

content of App.js

```
import ChatScreen from './chat'
    class ChatActivity extends Component {
      static navigationOptions = {
        ...
      }
      render() {
        return(
            <ChatScreen navigation={this.props.navigation} />
        )
      }
    }
```

I also have chat.js that contains the chat component. Chat.js itself, needs to `import Fire from './fire.js'`

so now, `this.props.navigation` was only passed to `Chat.js`...but I need to access it from `fire.js` as well.

I've read about `import {useNavigation}`, but from what i have tried it didn't work cause my `fire.js` doesn't even look like the example in the docs

this is my `fire.js`

```
class Fire extends React.Component{
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.init()
    this.checkAuth()
  }
  init = () => {
        firebase.initializeApp({

        })
  };

  checkAuth = () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (!user) {
        firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
      }
    })
  } 
  send = messages  => {
    messages.forEach(item => {
      const message = {
        text: item.text,
        timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
       // image: item.image,
        //video: item.video,
        user: item.user
      }
      this.db.child(`NEED NAVIGATION PARAMS HERE`).push(message)

    })
  }  

  parse = message => {
    const {user, text, timestamp} = message.val();
    const {key, _id} = message
    const createdAt = new Date(timestamp)

    return {
      _id,
      createdAt,
      text,
      user
    }
  }

  get = callback => {
    this.db.child(`NEED NAVIGATION PARAMS HERE`).on('child_added', snapshot => callback(this.parse(snapshot)))
  }

  off() {
    this.db.off()
  }

  get db() {
    return firebase.database().ref(`NEED NAVIGATION PARAMS HERE`);
  }

  get uid(){
    return(firebase.auth().currentUser || {}).uid
  }
}

export default new Fire();
```

Since i couldn't access navigation params, I tried `AsyncStorage`, but thats probably not the best practice and it isn't working too well. Not sure if its the `AsyncStorage` or `react-native-gifted-chat` but when I load the chat page once, it shows the same messages for other chats till I restart the app which shouldn't be cause i'm fetching the data based on unique parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just missed one step here...

Since you have passed the **navigation** as props by using the following approach:

```
<ChatScreen navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

the chat screen gets to use navigation properties of **ChatActivity**.

For **Fire.js** to be able to use the navigation as well, that was provided to **Chat.js** by **ChatActivity** you will need to pass the navigation props received by **Chat.js** to **Fire.js** in the same way.

This is how your **Chat.js** should look like:

```
import Fire from './Fire'

class Chat extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        ...
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <Fire navigation={this.props.navigation} />
        )
    }
}
```

That should solve the issue. Cheers!

Comment: Hii, thank you for your answer..just tried it, im getting this error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation')`...This is how i call it out `constructor (props) {
    this.init()
    this.checkAuth()
    this.state = {
      userid: this.props.navigation.state.params.userid,
      sellerid: this.props.navigation.state.params.sellerid
    }
  }`

Comment: Are you there ?

Comment: Which screen do you get this error at? Fire.js or Chat.js ?

Comment: Fire.js .I dont get the error if i dont call navigation props in Fire.js. Dont know if you missed it, but my fire.js is aexported as a function not a class...maybe thats why it doesn't work for it

Comment: @kunlee Review this snack and test it out : https://snack.expo.io/rxuhGMq57

Comment: The snack works, but its quite different from what i'm doing, you have 2 screens, i also have 2 screens but one of the screens is importing from another js file..its that other js file thats needs access to props.navigation....[link](https://snack.expo.io/@ad8kunle/my-chat-firebase) - that's my own snack with my code. clicking on an item in `seller.js` leads to `chat.js`...chat.js `imports Fire from fire.js` ...`fire.js` creates the chat room, to do this it needs access to the navigation parameters passed from `seller.js`

Comment: Fixed it by joining both chat.js and fire.js. always knew that would work but i'm new to react-native, so i wanted to know how its really done rather than just cutting corners

Comment: Great to hear mate.

Comment: @kunlee As per you question.. my solution provides appropriate  solution. So as a contributor, can you flag my solution as the correct accepted answer.. it would really help a lot of other people new to React native as well.